# What data structure should I use? HashTable, Array...?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, data-structures, hashtable

I have to save, permanently (or at least until next execution), a table like:

```
|  ID  |  Color  |
|------|---------|
| 0001 |  Red    |
| 0002 |  Blue   |
| 0003 |  Green  |
```

I was thinking to save it externally in a XML file but I don't know which data structure should I use internally to access this data, because I want some kind of iterative element but fast and easy to access and save into a external XML file, and if I want to add a new relation the ID must be `0004`.

I mean, should I use Hashtable, DataTable, Array...? Should I change the way to export this relationships or the best (easy and fast) way is to export them into a XML file?

Comment: Please note that data type you use to store a collection of elements is related to your run-time requirements (at least performance, memory usage and usage pattern - insert/delete/search speed). You do not have to keep same structure when you make data persistent (for example an hashtable may simply be stored a bulk set of nodes). Storage requirements are another story with different choices: do you have to manually edit that file? Use it as exchange format? It must be particularly small? Do you have to handle versioning?

Comment: What about a list? The id may be just the list index. There is too less information what you actually need to do with this data, what the ID means, how you access it etc. However it most probably is opinion based anyway.

Comment: ID thing _may_ be little bit more tricky because you can't simply use number of items in the collection to know next ID (unless you forbid deletions). How to get next ID can be as easy as a query to find currently used one (if concurrency and speed/collection size aren't an issue) otherwise you need to store _next ID_ (or latest one...) somewhere (eventually keeping thread-safe)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The data will grow logarithmically to stabilize (I calculate below 100) depending on the number of executions. I just need and ID and a string, so don't need large size in the file to save it. I just want a fast and easy method to modify and to import and export the data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since generics there is almost no reason to use `Hashtable` anymore.
The best way to store these values in memory is the generic dictionary (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). So assuming your "ID" is an `int` and your "Color" is a `string`, use: `Dictionary<int, string>`. These dictionaries are fast (O(1)-operation), and they do not need any casts like the `Hashtable` does.

For storing it in a file, there are multiple options. You could try putting the dictionary inside a class, and store the whole class to an XML-file using:

- or `XmlSerializer` (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)
- or `DataContractSerializer` (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with DataTable if converting records into XML is your intention.  It has `DataTable.WriteXml()` method which nicely gets your job done.

But if you need faster access and some manipulation, go with Dictionary. It is much faster than DataTable atleast in accessing.

Answer (score 0):

How much data is there? Does it change? How is the data accessed?

If there are millions of rows that do not change and lookups are always by id then a `Dictionary<int, Color>` is likely to be best.

If there are a few tens of rows, that is updated and accessed by either field a simple array of a custom type (id and color properties) doing simple linear lookup is likely to be best (not needing to maintain the data order saves enough to have a more expensive lookup).

(In either case, as you're doing all the work in memory, a simple persistence format will be best: gives you the flexibility at runtime where you need it.)
Any real situation will fall between. In the end, if performance is important enough you'll try one way and measure; then another way and measure. (Hence a little abstraction to hide the internal details is the important place to start.) Repeat until you meet your performance requirements.

Comment: The data will grow logarithmically to stabilize (I calculate below 100) depending on the number of executions. I just need and ID and a string, so don't need large size in the file to save it. I just want a fast and easy method to modify and to import and export the data. Thanks

Comment: @JoseMMartin At that size pretty much anything will be fast: you don't have enough data to create slow downs.